# (include_path='C:/xampp/php/pear') in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, xampp, include

I've been having this issue while using Xampp for a while now.

I have my PHP files in the htdocs folder.

I am running Apache, MySQL, and Filezilla on xampp and I've checked the folders for the PEAR.php file, and the path seems correct to me in the php.ini file.

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = "C:\xampp\php\pear"
```

Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/gamingalliance/WEBSHOP/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php;\C:\xampp\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: I think the issue is clear in your mind but you didn't really transmit it when composing the question. Have you written PHP code? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I havent actually programmed anything yet, but even on older projects it is giving me the same error message while trying to open localhost.

Comment: Fine, `failed opening required...` is an error message. But `C:/xampp/htdocs/gamingalliance/WEBSHOP/index.php` does not look a built-in Xampp module.

Comment: gamingalliance is the directory of the website that i'm trying to make, this exact website has ran on Xampp before, about 2 weeks ago? Now when  I just tried opening this website to see if this one worked, but on this new project of mine, I haven't written any PHP yet, I have a clean index.php which gives the exact same error message.

Comment: Ah... You mean you get that message when you run PHP code through Apache, even an empty script, right?

Comment: Exactly, I'm currently trying reinstalling Xampp with a newer version, but I'm clueless tbh.

Comment: EDIT: I think I fixed it, it shows me the website without any errors now.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you think it's a generic issue that may affect others, feel free to answer your own question. Otherwise you can remove the question altogether.